# How to implement a white or empty arrow into a circuit?

Tags: circuitikz

I've read the circuitikz documentation already and there is not such a symbol (not at least in the documentation) comparable with the white/empty arrow on the upper right corner of the circuit (marked as voltage V0). Is there a way of doing so? I am not looking for a current arrow.
[image: Impedance circuit]

### EDIT:

Here is the circuit code.

```
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (2,0)--(0,0) node[ground]{} to[sV, v=\textit{vi=4Vpp}] (0,2) to[R, l=\textit{r}$_0$\textit{=50$\Omega$}](2,2) to[open] (2,0)--(5.5,0);
\draw (2,2) to[short, *-] (2,1.3) to[short] (2.75,1.3) to[short] (2.75,1.65) to[short, i=$ $] (2.75,2);
\draw (2,2) to[R, l^=$10K\Omega$] (3.5,2) to[short] (4,2);
\draw (3.5,2) -- (4.5,2) to[short, *-*] (5.5,2) to[short] (5.8,2) to[short, i=$ $] (6,2);
\draw (4.5,2) to[R, l_=$10K\Omega$] (4.5,0);
\draw (5.5,2) to[R, l=$5K\Omega$] (5.5,0);
\draw (4.25,1.6) -- (4.25,2.2) to[short] (4.3,2.2) to[short, i=$Z_A$] (4.5,2.2);
\draw (4,2) to[short, -o] (4,2.3);
\draw (4.4,2.5)to[open, l=$A$] (4.4,2.7);
\end{circuitikz}
\captionof{figure}{\small Impedance circuit.}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You can simply add an arrow with that head and a node at the end. It will be better if you post the code you have tried already, starting from `\documentclass{}...` and ending at `\end{document}` for us to be specific. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar I added the circuit code, I can't find useful to add all the document class and everything.

Comment: @Hans: however, we always ask to post complete [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than code snippets because this really helps people to answer you. Maybe from your point of view is useless, however consider the extra effort people does in adding the correct packages, libraries and perhaps custom commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A work around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (2,0)--(0,0) node[ground]{} to[sV, v=\textit{vi=4Vpp}] (0,2) to[R, l=\textit{r}$_0$\textit{=50$\Omega$}](2,2) to[open] (2,0)--(5.5,0);
\draw (2,2) to[short, *-] (2,1.3) to[short] (2.75,1.3) to[short] (2.75,1.65) to[short, i=$ $] (2.75,2);
\draw (2,2) to[R, l^=$10K\Omega$] (3.5,2) to[short] (4,2);
\draw (3.5,2) -- (4.5,2) to[short, *-*] (5.5,2) to[short] (5.8,2);% to[short, i=$$] (6,2);
 \draw[-open triangle 45] (5.8,2)--(7,2)node[right] {V0};
\draw (4.5,2) to[R, l_=$10K\Omega$] (4.5,0);
\draw (5.5,2) to[R, l=$5K\Omega$] (5.5,0);
\draw (4.25,1.6) -- (4.25,2.2) to[short] (4.3,2.2) to[short, i=$Z_A$] (4.5,2.2);
\draw (4,2) to[short, -o] (4,2.3);
\draw (4.4,2.5)to[open, l=$A$] (4.4,2.7);
\end{circuitikz}
\captionof{figure}{\small Impedance circuit.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As an additional remark concerning units: There is package `siunitx` taking care of almost everything.